# Limitations for Google Speech to text Model Adaptation Apis

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

I aim to use the google model adaptation to improve the speech to text accuracy, but these APIs are not well documented anywhere.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/projects.locations.customClasses

I tried to create a custom class with 200000 values. And above that count, it is giving an error for the size of the payload and not for the entries count limit.
Where can I find the proper information/details of API and its restriction.

I am using the Ruby library to create custom classes.

Code to create the custom class .

```
cname = "TestClass"
items = 3_00_000.times.map{|e| Google::Cloud::Speech::V1p1beta1::CustomClass::ClassItem.new(value: Faker::Name.name) };
_class = Google::Cloud::Speech::V1p1beta1::CustomClass.new(name: cname, items: items);
request = Google::Cloud::Speech::V1p1beta1::CreateCustomClassRequest.new({custom_class: _class, parent: "projects/<projectID>/locations/global", custom_class_id: cname})
_klass = client.create_custom_class request
```

Getting the following error looks like it's being created/updated with the 10_000_000 values.

```
Google::Cloud::InvalidArgumentError: 3:Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.. debug_error_string:{"created":"@1628230030.306827000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.251.42.10:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.","grpc_status":3}
```

Comment: Please provide overview of you process. You are using this adaptation as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/adaptation-model#improve_transcription_results_using_a_customclass)? What exactly error are you getting? Your audio file is in GCS or on your local machine? Are you using Synchronous, Asynchronous or Streaming Requests? Overal Speech-to-text quota can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas).

Comment: Any limits / quotas information is listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas)

Comment: @PjoterS yes I am using the same API for adaptation using custom class tokens. I have added the error in the question.

Comment: @MBHAPhoenix thanks but, the link is for the speech to text apis and not for the model adaptation apis.

Comment: Could you share your code/steps without private information? Your request is takine audio file from your machine or GCS? `Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes` suggests that your file is 10MB+. How long is your audio file and and how many MB it has? If your are using audio longer than 1 minute it's suggested to use Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: The API i am calling is not speech to text but creating the custom class. No audio file being uploaded.  added code for creating the custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the publicly available documentation about the API.

```
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/release-notes
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/sla
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/support#troubleshooting
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/apis
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/concepts
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/how-to
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/tutorials
```